# If $a \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that gcd$(a, a+2)$ is $1$ if $a$ is odd and $2$ if $a$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Once again the problem is:

If 'a' is an element of N, prove that gcd(a, a+2) is 1 if 'a' is an odd number, and 2 is 'a' is an even number.

I really have no idea on how to prove this, and I'm brand new to induction proofs. Can anyone help explain it?

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ divides $a$ and $a+2$, it divides their difference as well.